# How I can deserialize this json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need some help to deserialize this json, in particular the API request return a response that contains multiple json like this:

```
{"trace":{"details":{"[date]":"[27-02-2016 9:47:00.666970]","[level]":"[info]","[message]":"[System Done.]"},"context":[]}}
{"trace":{"details":{"[date]":"[27-02-2016 9:47:00.677366]","[level]":"[info]","[message]":"[Trace Done.]"},"context":[[{"ID":"John Doe"}]]}}
```

how you can see above there is two json returned. This is actual my class:

```
class Foo
{
    public class Details
    {
       public string date { get; set; }
       public string level { get; set; }
       public string message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trace
    {
        public Details details { get; set; }
        //context?
    }
    public void getJson()
    {
        string responseText = Connection.Request("api call");

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(responseText);
        Console.WriteLine(responseText);
    }
}
```

the variable `responseText` contains the two json above, I need to iterate each line of `trace` and deserialize it, someone could help me to achieve this?

Comment: `I need to iterate each line`  that is not valid json, but if it were, you would likely deserialize to an array or list of items

Comment: Just deserialize the json to a list and iterate. It cant be more simple than that.

Comment: So the user sends two json objects in one request? This is not really how one is supposed to do that, you could send them as an array: like `[json1,json2]`.

Comment: Use DataContractJsonSerializer. Enjoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking a class definition for the line. Then you should split your response string by lines and deserialize each of them.

```
using System.Linq;   
...
class Foo
{
    public class ResponseLine
    {
        public Trace trace { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
       public string date { get; set; }
       public string level { get; set; }
       public string message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trace
    {
        public Details details { get; set; }
        public Context[][] context { get; set; }
    }

    public void getJson()
    {
        string responseText = Connection.Request("api call");
        Console.WriteLine(responseText);

        // responseText is not valid JSON, need to split it by lines
        // before deserializing.
        var traces = responseText.Split('\n')
            .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
            .Select(l => JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<ResponseLine>(l))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I have added what looks like required for the `context` property. But I guess this array of array may contains other properties than the `ID` shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Json.NET to deserialize your json result and map it to your classes ! 
[Get JSON.net from here :)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: This is no valid file as it is shown on the question. The serializer will not do.

Answer (score 0):

First you separate them, since you say there are on different lines, just use ReadAllLines to get an array of strings. Then you iterate and deserialize. You end up with a list of Details objects.

```
 string[] strs = response.Split(new char[]{'\n'});
 List<Details>list new List<Details>();
 foreach(string str in str)
 {
     list.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details>(str));
 }
```

Comment: `response` is not a file name `File.ReadAllLines(response)` => [`NotSupportedException`: *path* is in an invalid format.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: True, it should be split.